# Converting Pandas dataframe to csv with best performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

Is there any better solution to convert pandas dataframe to csv than .to_csv module?

The given dataframe is huge and the csv file created from it is about 50Gb's that's why I'm seeking for a better solution.

The dataframe contains only strings.

For now I tried converting to numpy  and the np.savetxt() function although It doesn't improve the performance. Any ideas?

Comment: Look into [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html) to process huge dataframes. You could store it in [hdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) for example.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen It looks great. I will check it out in a while and let you know. Thanks!